# yolo5 training problems, such as NameError: name 'Path' is not defined

Tags: python, opencv, pytorch, yolo

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\yolov5-5.0\yolov5-5.0\train.py", line 543, in <module>
train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer)
File "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\yolov5-5.0\yolov5-5.0\train.py", line 88, in train
model = Model(opt.cfg or ckpt['model'].yaml, ch=3, nc=nc, anchors=hyp.get('anchors')).to(device)  # create
File "C:\Users\Gary\Desktop\yolov5-5.0\yolov5-5.0\models\yolo.py", line 73, in __init__
self.yaml_file = Path(cfg).name
NameError: name 'Path' is not defined
```

please, how to solve those problems?

Comment: Are you sure you have imported pathlib? As `from pathlib import Path`?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import `Path` which you can do so using `from pathlib import Path`

Comment: You are welcome @GaryZhou - please select my response as the answer (the tick on the left side). Thanks